# Do images stay loaded when passed through a functions return

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have the following code that I have written in `Javascript`:

```js
function newImage(name) {
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        loaded++;
        console.log("Loading: " + Math.round(loaded / 6 * 100) + "% complete");
    };
    img.src = "./assets/" + name;
    return img;
}
var img1 = newImage("img1");
var img2 = newImage("img2");
var img3 = newImage("img3");
```

I want to know if the image that starts loading in the `img` variable stays loaded when it is returned to the `img1` variable. As in, it will not re-run the onload function.

Comment: Yeah it will return img and it will stays in `img1` variable

Comment: I am not asking if it stays in the img1 variable, I am asking if it will have to load again, therefor rerunning the onload function and getting the img from ./assets/img1 again. I will edit the post to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is the image won't be downloaded again.
Here's a fiddle you can use to see that: 
https://jsfiddle.net/uglynakedguy/eu4okzpx/7/

```
function newImage(name) {
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        loaded++;
        console.log("Loading: " + Math.round(loaded / 6 * 100) + "% complete");
    };
    img.src = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500";
    return img;
}

var imageLoaded = newImage("img1");

document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.add')) return;
    document.body.appendChild(imageLoaded);
}, false);
```

If you check the JS, it has your function. First thing we do when page loads is getting the image. Then, when you click on the button, we inject your image in the page.

You will see that if the image has been loaded, when we inject it, it renders SUPER FAST, it is not downloaded again. You can prove that in network tab too, it will be listed once.